# Why does rails use id as primary key and should I index over other columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, primary-key

I understand Ruby on Rails uses `id` as the primary key attribute for all its tables. I understand it's convenient since the id is always distinct, auto increments, and is easy to index on (I think), but I'm wondering if I should build an index over other attributes, and if that is possible.

I have a web app where users can upload images into portfolios, so granted I have `User`, `Portfolio`, and `Image`, and the `Image` table has two columns that are:

```
:user_id
:portfolio_id
```

So sometimes I may want to pick all images belonging to a certain user or all images in a certain portfolio, or in a range of portfolios, etc'

Should I make Rails build an index over attributes I am searching over frequently? and if so, is there a way to do that? are there any drawbacks to doing that?

I remember reading some time ago there are gems to make rails include other fields as part of the primary key, but what if I just want to build an index over them without including them in primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, making indexes on columns you use for search frequently is a good idea and encouraged.

In your working directory:

```
rails generate migration add_indexes_to_images
```

This will generate a migration file, you can then edit the file to add your indexes:

```
class AddIndexesToImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change    
    add_index :images, :user_id
    add_index :images, :portfolio_id
  end
end
```

[Read more about migrations and all the things they can do.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)